# Variable scope in SSIS config table

Tags: ssis, config

I'm trying to change the scope of some of my variables in my SSIS package. They rely on a config table in a database, and previously they got their values set with the following values in the database:

```
\Package.Variables[User::EmailAddress].Properties[Value]
```

And the value for that would be set in the ConfigurationValue column.

This worked like a charm, except once I changed the scope of the variable from package to a specific foreach loop container, I've gotten the following error:

`Warning: The package path referenced an object that cannot be found: "\Package.Variables[User::EmailAddress].Properties[Value]". This occurs when an attempt is made to resolve a package path to an object that cannot be found.`

The other, globally-scoped variables don't have this problem. Is there some value in this string that's telling SSIS to look at the package level, instead of in the entire package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go one of two ways - either rebuild the DTSConfig using the wizard, or alter the path in file to include the `ForEach Loop`

```
\Package\ForEachLoopName.Variables[User::EmailAddress].Properties[Value]
```

Comment: Editing the value didn't work. Now the error reads: Warning: The package path referenced an object that cannot be found: "\Package.DownloadFiles.Variables[User::EmailAddress].Properties[Value]". This occurs when an attempt is made to resolve a package path to an object that cannot be found.

Comment: In that case, rename your old DTSConfig, and create a new one from the package with the variable that you need.  Then copy the path over to the original file, and swap them.

Comment: Raj is on the right track with the second approach. It's just a matter of determining the proper scope of the variable. Bring up the properties window (F4) and then point at the Variable in question. You should be able to access the `PackagePath` property and as long as you don't flub any of the casing, it should work fine

Comment: Alright, you were close, Raj. It should be \Package\ForEachLoopName.Variables[User::EmailAddress].Properties[Value] If you could edit that in, I'll mark this as answered.